# How to generate enumerated tuples from a dictionary with a list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python

How can I write a list comprehension to enumerate key: value pairs into 3-membered tuples from a Python dictionary?

```
d = {'one': 'val1', 'two': 'val2', 'three': 'val3', 'four': 'val4', 'five': 'val5'}
```

When I try this:

```
li = [(index, k, val) for index, k, val in enumerate(d.items())]
```

I get a `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`

The desired output would be:

```
[(0, 'one', 'val1'),
 (1, 'two', 'val2'),
 (2, 'three', 'val3'),
 (3, 'four', 'val4'),
 (4, 'five', 'val5')]
```

Comment: You are assuming that your dictionary is ordered but dictionaries are unordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nest your tuples. But the order may not be as desired.

```
li = [(index, k, val) for index, (k, val) in enumerate(d.items())]
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of enumerate() is a 2-element tuple. Since the value of that tuple is another 2-element tuple, you need to use parentheses to group them.

```
li = [(index, k, val) for index, (k, val) in enumerate(d.items())]
```

However, since a dict is by default unordered, you need to create an OrderedDict.

```
odict = collections.OrderedDict()
odict['one'] = 'val1'
odict['two'] = 'val2'
odict['three'] = 'val3'
odict['four'] = 'val4'

li = [(index, k, val) for (index, (k, val)) in enumerate(odict.items())]
```

This would give you the following value for `li`

```
[(0, 'one', 'val1'), (1, 'two', 'val2'), (2, 'three', 'val3'), (3, 'four', 'val4')]
```